# "Cannot read property ClassList of Undefined" error after moving Javascript into modules

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, export

I'm very new to JS and am running into an issue while trying to separate some JS into modules. I'm thinking that this is a simple fix, but I'm hoping someone here can help steer me in the right direction. My code works fine if I just put it all into one JS file and link it directly with index.html via a  tag, so something is breaking specifically from the move over to a module.

Within my HTML, I have several  elements that will change visibility depending on the buttons a user clicks while on the site. The JS as it was written in the original script file worked fine before I attempt to place it in a module:

```
showHideSections = (section) => {
if (section.classList.contains("hidden")){
    section.classList.remove("remove-tab");
    section.classList.remove("slideout");
     ... };
```

So, I added export const to the start of the code to export it to a main.js file:

```
export const showHideSections = (section) => { ...
```

And then imported it to main.js:

```
import { ..., showHideSections, ... } from "./modules/script.js"

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
...
showHideSections();
... });
```

And now I'm ending up with Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property "ClassList" of undefined.

I'm guessing this has to do with the order in which the code is running now that the JS has moved into a module, but after a few attempts with directing the code to execute differently, I'm feeling stuck. I've tried adjusting the addEventListener on main.js to execute on "load" vs on DOM Content loading. I have also tried creating an object for the  element within the script.js file as a workaround, but no dice there, either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you are not passing the section argument in the method call:

```
import { ..., showHideSections, ... } from "./modules/script.js"

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const section = document.querySelector("#someSelectorHere");
  showHideSections(section);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment! So, are you saying something like this?

showHideSections(section);

This returns a new, Uncaught ReferenceError on main.js that section is not defined. Apologies if I'm misinterpreting your suggestion.

Comment: I also just tried creating a new function above the showHideSections function, containing a document.getElementsbyTagName("section"), and exporting that. No go, same error.

Comment: In script.js you defined a function that receives an argument named section and uses it in a condition. Later you import that function and don't send it that argument, so you either send it or modify your condition. also, if you're trying to get a specific element, give it an id/class and get by using document.querySelector("#yourIdHere");

Comment: To your first point, how would you send the argument to main.js in this scenario? Sorry for the beginner questions, I'm having a tough time finding the answer.

Comment: For the second point, the issue I assume I'll run into is that because I have a number of different classes assigned to <section>, I need to use element.ClassList in my JS in order to remove/add sections appropriately. From my understanding, if I target a specific class using querySelector, I won't be able to modify the other classes as I've only selected the one, correct? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Using an identifier to catch an element is just a way of finding a specific element, it doesn't strip it of any attributes. Having a class/id just makes it easier to target the desired element instead of looking for it by tags/other attributes. I've modified the answer to also get an element.